# HTML5 File upload with AngularJS

Tags: html, file-upload, angularjs

I'm trying to get angular to read the contents of a file that the user selects through an `<input type="file"` control. Even though angular does not have directives for file upload controls, it should be easy to fix that with a call to `$apply`:

```
function MyController($scope) {
  $('#myFile').on('change', function() {
    var that = this;
    $scope.$apply(function() { $scope.files = that.files });
  });
}
```

Unfortunately, the event is never fired. It's like the selector is unable to refer to the correct DOM element: even though the selector finds the element, the list of files is always empty. This also happens if i poke around with the js console. The DOM inspector instead has the file list among its properties.

It's driving me crazy, but the only way I've got it to work so far is to use an inline event handler that assigns to a global variable. Why is the jquery selector returning another item? Is there some template compilation mumbo-jumbo that angular does which confuses selectors?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is what I do:

http://plnkr.co/edit/JPxSCyrxosVXfZnzEIuS?p=preview

```
app.directive('filelistBind', function() {
  return function( scope, elm, attrs ) {
    elm.bind('change', function( evt ) {
      scope.$apply(function() {
        scope[ attrs.name ] = evt.target.files;
        console.log( scope[ attrs.name ] );
      });
    });
  };
});
```

template:

```
<input type="file" filelist-bind name="files"/>
<p>selected files : <pre>{{ files | json }}</pre></p>
```

This kind of task, you definitely want to make use of directive.
But I think that your main concern is how to access the selected file
objects and my example should clarify that.

Comment: nice. I ended up defining a global function in the controller, and calling it from the inline event handler. Since $scope is in the outer closure, at least I can $apply the changes. The directive is definitely a more "angular" way to do it. But the question stands: why does the selector returns an `input` element that looks exactly like the one the user is interacting with, but it actually isn't?

Comment: mmmh this doesn't work for me. if I run your plunkr, I always get
files :
{
  "0": {}
}
do I do something wrong?

Comment: @pomarc IIRC, it used to work... But it seems that modern browsers do not support stringifying File object.  You have to directly access properties in order to show them in your view.

Comment: Here's a fork of Tosh's example that works in modern browsers. http://plnkr.co/edit/peDONwopzkEeELg3cRvR?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for file upload with angular you can use this plugin

https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload

It is basically a directive like tosh's answer that takes care of non-HTML5 browsers with FileAPI flash polyfill and has $http.uploadFile function to upload the actual file via AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

This [site](http://www.codingterminal.com/articles/052015/2/Angular%20JS%20and%20HTML5%20File%20Upload.php) uses Angular service for HTML5 File Upload. A simple way is to setup a controller which calls the service and updates the UI when the asynchronous call is completed.

controller:

```
 myapp.controller('fileUploadCtrl', ['$scope', '$q', 'FileInputService', function ($scope, $q, FileInputService) {
            $scope.fileInputContent = "";
            $scope.onFileUpload = function (element) {
                $scope.$apply(function (scope) {
                    var file = element.files[0];
                    FileInputService.readFileAsync(file).then(function (fileInputContent) {
                        $scope.fileInputContent = fileInputContent;
                    });
                });
            };
        }]);
```

service:

```
myapp.service('FileInputService', function ($q) {

    this.readFileAsync = function (file) {
        var deferred = $q.defer(),
        fileReader = new FileReader(),
        fileReader.readAsText(file);

        fileReader.onload = function (e) {
            deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
        };
        return deferred.promise;
    };
});
```

template:

```
Choose File <input type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().onFileUpload(this)">
<br />
{{fileInputContent}}
```

**Reference:** You can find the full source code and reference [on this site.](http://www.codingterminal.com/articles/052015/2/Angular%20JS%20and%20HTML5%20File%20Upload.php)